# Why can't I save new contacts to my phone or SIM?

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow

I just bought the quite new Moto G4+, which comes with Android Marshmallow (6.1) preloaded, without any layer added by the constructor.

Upon the first use of the phone, I linked my Google account. When I want to add a new contact (via the Contacts app), there is no choice for the place where the new contact will be saved. Normally there are (at least) three choices: save (sync) to the Google account, or to the phone (internal memory), or to the SIM. Whatever I do, the contact will be saved in the Google account only. When I disable the synchronization with the Google account, the contacts are saved to the phone, but I have no option to sync a particular contact. How can I do to enable these three choices upon the creation of a new contact?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the moment I have done the following: disconnect my Google account, add contacts into the phone, reconnect my Google account. But now, when I want to add a new contact, Android tells me that it will be synchronized with the Google account, there is still no choice.

Comment: Looks like your device lacks a separate "local account provider". There's an app named [MyLocalAccount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.mylocalaccount) (from the makers of *MyPhoneExplorer)* providing such, but it seems no longer maintained (last update in 2013). Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any alternatives to that. On a second thought: Using a CardDAV provider might work, but most likely will require a valid counterpart to configure.

Comment: @Izzy: Thank you very much, I just added the app you indicated me, it works very well. Actually, this issue is well-known; see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26834.

Comment: So shall I make this an answer, as it obviously solved your issue? // Edit: Done that. If it solved your issue, please "accept" the answer by ticking the green check-mark next to it, so other people affected by this issue can easily identify the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already found out yourself, this is a [well known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26834). Looks like your device lacks a separate "local account provider".

To work around that issue, there's an app named [MyLocalAccount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.mylocalaccount) (from the makers of *MyPhoneExplorer)* providing such, but it seems no longer maintained (last update in 2013) – but after my comment with that, you were able to confirm it still does its job.

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any alternatives to that. On a second thought: Using a CardDAV provider might work, but most likely will require a valid counterpart to configure. If you want to try that approach, you can find some [in my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_sync#group_70).